# How to populate 2D boolean array between two coordinates?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to create a daily time block for my calendar app. I have an idea of creating a 2D array representing all the minute in a day:

```
final int hour = 24, min = 60; 
boolean dayBlock[][] = new boolean [hour][min];

//Initialize the array. true = available, false = 
busy.
for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        dayBlock[j][i] = true; 
    }
}
```

However, I'm struggling how to write an algorithm to populate from (startHour, startMin) to (endHour, endMin) for an event with precision.

Since I'm doing this for multiple events, I can't just go over and then backtrack since it will mess up the previous event time-block.

Comment: `daily time block for my calendar app` till what time would calendar app handle the events? You are storing this in a 2D array, which means `24 * 60 * 365 = 525600` bits for 1 calendar year is needed. Now, if a few years pass since then, you app would crash saying `OutOfMemoryError`.  I suggest you to first decide the storing medium and then deal with algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

To mark something ranging from `(startHour, startMin)` to `(endHour, endMin)`

```
// mark false for the remaining minutes in first hour
for (int i = startMin; i < 60; i++) {
    dayBlock[startHour][i] = false;
}

// mark false for every minute after first hour and before last hour
for (int j = startHour+1; j < endHour; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        dayBlock[j][i] = false; 
    }
}

// mark false for the remaining minutes in last hour
for (int i = 0; i < endMin; i++) {
    dayBlock[endHour][i] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should probably rethink your idea of using a 2D array.
You are trying to represent time, which is naturally not two dimensional, but one dimensional.

Instead of a 2D array, why not use simple 1D array like this:

`boolean dayBlock[] = new boolean[hour * minute];`

To calculate where a given time is represented in the array, just use:

`int start = theHour * 60 + theMinute;`

Comment: You're right, I should have thought about that. That would everything simpler. Thanks !!

Comment: I wouldn't go with that either. Time has ultimately no scale and why would you limit the calendar accuracy to minutes? What about events that span multiple days? I would just go with a list of events, ordered by start time. A data structure called "IntervalTree" might be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be to think of an imaginary index for your 2d array from 0 to 1440 (24*60), which enables you to make something like below for your params `(startHour, startMin) (endHour, endMin)`:

```
    int startHour = 6;
    int startMin = 15; 
    int endHour = 8;
    int endMin = 0;
    int strat = startHour * 60 + startMin;
    int end = endHour * 60 + endMin;

    for(int i = strat; i <= end; i++){
        dayBlock[i/60][i%60] = false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Take input from user for start and end hour and start and end minuted and validate the boundary values.

int startHour,endHour,startMinute,endMinute;
for (int j = startHour; j <= endHour; j++) {
    int i = 0;
    if(j==startHour){
       i= startMinute;
    }
    for (; i < 60; i++) {
        if(j==endHour && i> endMinute) {
           break;
        }
        dayBlock[j][i] = ;// if busy set false or true if available. 
    }
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for startHour = 6, startMin = 0, endHour = 8, endMin = 0 since the inner loop would never get executed

Comment: Still doesn't work for startHour = 6, startMin = 30, endHour = 7, endMin = 15. It only marks the time from 6:30-7:00, but the time between 7:00-7:15 stays the same.

Comment: Still not working for the same parameter values. Please properly test your code before updating

Comment: @Andreas why not working for the same parameters ? can you explain ?

Comment: I run that and it simply marks from 6:00-7:15 instead of 6:30-7:15

Comment: @Andreas it runs prefectly fine on my machine. run again